# Fade in background image in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to fade in a background image (such as the image of a BoxDecoration), but I find no solution in the docs.

I need to be able to draw widgets on top of the image, and I need it to fade in since it's a NetworkImage.

FadeInImage does not work as background for DecorationImage since it requires an ImageProvider.

Is there a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Stack()` and place the background image below your actual content, then use `AnimatedOpacity()` to fade in or out. You can then use the image either as a decoration image with

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage('test'))

    ),
  ),
```

Also, there are factory constructors for images, i.e.

```
Image.network(), Image.asset(),FadeInImage.assetNetwork
```

Comment: Of course! Coming from Xamarin I confused the Flutter Stack with Xamarin's StackLayout, which stacks children horizontally or vertically, not like a stack of cards like this.

Answer (score 0):

After placing the background image below your actual content, and using `AnimatedOpacity()` to fade in or out just like @DanielSzy mentioned, you can equally use an image as a decoration image as follows for images hosted within the app's assets:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('images/drawer.jpg')
    ),
),
```

Where `'images/drawer.jpg'` is the path to your image in question.

Also make sure to configure your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
```